# Wordpress post migration to google cloud issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I migrated a client website recently and I could only access the wordpress admin(http://35.188.112.217/wp-admin/) and not the actual site using (http://35.188.112.217). I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: Disable all your plugins and see what happens. If that doesn't work, check your custom functions (if you have any) and comment them out as well.

Comment: if you are using any child theme or any other theme than wordpress default theme try to change to the wordpress default theme

Comment: Did you pointed your domain A record to this IP?

Comment: You are getting ```HTTP ERROR 500``` which indicates in many cases PHP error. Please verify that you have changed the domain in your database.

Comment: @GroupOfOceninfo I will try that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Point your domain A Record to IP 35.188.112.217
2. Wordpress Settings > Update WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to with your domain abc.com or www.abc.com